# VB.NET: Convert multiline string into single line

Tags: vb.net

I'm grabbing the HTML source code of a webpage and try to convert it to a single-line string but I can't.

This is my code:

```
Dim source As String = client.DownloadString("http://www.whocallsme.gr/el/master/lookup/19588")
source = source.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
```

I also tried using Environment.NewLine and vbNewLine instead of vbCrLf but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
source = source.Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "")
```